# JQuery code having no effect on Google Chrome but working perfectly in Firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox, google-chrome, mootools

I use a piece of JQuery code with a bit of Mootools to change the class of some inputs but the thing is that it doesn't work (has no effect) in Google Chrome despite working perfectly in Firefox.

Edit :  I've discovered that if I click two times on the given element on the page the class gets effectively added.

my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var myCheck = new FormCheck('formulaire');
    $('votconj').addEvent('click', function() {
     // code inside works perfectly
});

$('votconj_no').addEvent('click', function() {
    // code inside works perfectly
});

$('nb_children').addEvent('click', function() {
  var selected = $('nb_children').getSelected();


  selected.each(function(element) {
  var val = element.get('value');
  for (var counter = 1; counter <= val; counter++) {
    $('jj_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required']");
    myCheck.register($('jj_enfant' + counter));
    $('mm_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required']");
    myCheck.register($('mm_enfant' + counter));
    $('aaaa_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required']");
    myCheck.register($('aaaa_enfant' + counter));
    $('last_name_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
    myCheck.register($('last_name_enfant' + counter));
    $('first_name_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
    myCheck.register($('first_name_enfant' + counter));
    // Here the good value is displayed
    alert(val);
  }

  for (var counter = parseInt(val)+1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    $('jj_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
    myCheck.dispose($('jj_enfant' + counter));
    $('mm_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
    myCheck.dispose($('mm_enfant' + counter));
    $('aaaa_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
    myCheck.dispose($('aaaa_enfant' + counter));
    $('last_name_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
    myCheck.dispose($('last_name_enfant' + counter));
    $('first_name_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
    myCheck.dispose($('first_name_enfant' + counter));
  }
  });
});

})
...
</script>
```

Comment: Open the page in Chrome, hit f12 to bring up the dev tools... are there any js errors listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works great (I've changed the event from click to blur and I've made the code a bit simpler and cleaner by getting only the last element of the array selected).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var myCheck = new FormCheck('formulaire');
    $('votconj').addEvent('click', function() {
      // code inside works
    });

    $('votconj_no').addEvent('click', function() {
     // code inside works
    });

    $('nb_children').addEvent('blur', function() {
       var selected = $('nb_children').getSelected();

       var element = selected.getLast();

       var val = element.get('value');
       for (var counter = 1; counter <= val; counter++) {
          $('jj_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required']");
          myCheck.register($('jj_enfant' + counter));
          $('mm_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required']");
          myCheck.register($('mm_enfant' + counter));
          $('aaaa_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required']");
          myCheck.register($('aaaa_enfant' + counter));
          $('last_name_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
          myCheck.register($('last_name_enfant' + counter));
          $('first_name_enfant' + counter).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
          myCheck.register($('first_name_enfant' + counter));
       }

       for (var counter = parseInt(val)+1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
          $('jj_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
          myCheck.dispose($('jj_enfant' + counter));
          $('mm_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
          myCheck.dispose($('mm_enfant' + counter));
          $('aaaa_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
          myCheck.dispose($('aaaa_enfant' + counter));
          $('last_name_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
          myCheck.dispose($('last_name_enfant' + counter));
          $('first_name_enfant' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
          myCheck.dispose($('first_name_enfant' + counter));
       }

    });

})
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `addEvent` method, neither in Firefox 6 or Chrome 13, at least not in Standards Compliance Mode. (Perhaps you wanted to use the `addEventListener` method?)

If you are using Quirks Mode some browsers are supporting some non-standard methods, but you can't use those methods if you want it to work cross browser.

Use the `ready` event in jQuery instead, which also emulates the `domready` event for browsers that doesn't support it (i.e. IE).

The jQuery method to bind event handlers is named `bind`, not `addEvent`. You can also use the `click` method to bind the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myCheck = new FormCheck('formulaire');
  $('votconj').click(function() {
    // ...
  });
  // ...
});
```

Note that there is no `votconj` element in HTML, so the selector above doesn't match anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried it and it doesn't work. AddEvent is part of Mootools and I'd prefer to stick with it (unless there's no other choice :-) ). (After all it's working on Firefox).

Comment: votconj is an html element of the page (www.mutuelle-de-sante.eu)

Comment: @Bruno: I see, I assumed that it was jQuery code as you tagged the question with jQuery. (In jQuery the selecor `'votconj'` looks for a `<votconj>` tag, not a tag with `id="votconj"`.)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use jQuery ready() for detecting when then the Dom is ready.
jQuery is intended to detect this event in a cross browser way

replace

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var myCheck = new FormCheck('formulaire');
    $('votconj').addEvent('click', function() {
    // code inside works perfectly
});
```

with

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var myCheck = new FormCheck('formulaire');
    $('votconj').addEvent('click', function() {
        // code inside works perfectly
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried it and it doesn't work.